# VLookup two values in R and match 10% difference of value

Tags: r, statistics

I have two systems:

```
> dput(system.1)
structure(list(`Id - System 2` = c(91L, 93L, 912323L, 6L, 9874L, 
875342L, 875342L, 875342L, 124523L, 91L), `Value - System 2` = c("12.342.314,00", 
"123.476,00", "762.341,00", "978.543,00", "100.000,00", "100.100,00", 
"20.120.310,00", "13", "15", "12.341.235,00")), .Names = c("Id - System 2", 
"Value - System 2"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000110788>)
> dput(system.2)
structure(list(`Id - System 1` = c(12345L, 124523L, 875342L, 
9874L, 45L), `Value - System 1` = c("10,00", "12,00", "100.000,00", 
"20,00", "9.872.341,00")), .Names = c("Id - System 1", "Value - System 1"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000110788>)
```

Basically I want to merge the ID and the value(which can be in a 10-20% range) of system 1 to system 2.

I tried a basic merge, `merge(system.2, system.1, by.x="Id - System 1", by.y="Id - System 2")`. However, that only matches one column at a time.

I guess the best result would be to have a table, which looks like that:

[image]

Any recommendation how this could be achieved with R?

I really appreciate your reply!

**Update**

This is my code so far:

```
df12 <- merge(sys1, sys2, by='ID')

subset(df12, abs(df12$Value.x-df12$Value.y)/df12$Value.y < 0.1)
```

Comment: Do it in two steps: `merge` and then take a subset of the result based on when the two values are close to each other.

Comment: @joran Thx for your reply! Would you be so kind to show me how this would look like in code?

Comment: I started to, but it was a hassle dealing with your data.table's awkward column names and the `<` in data.table's dput output, and then your "values" are actually stored as character values, and I"m not going to go through the trouble of converting them for you.

Comment: yes, the format you've given is not convenient, but something along the lines of `df12 <- merge(s2, s1, by='id')` and then `subset(df12, abs(v2-v1)/v1 < 0.1)` should give you those that have an id in both systems, and v2 (of system2) is within 10% of the v1 value.  Along with `gsub`bing your data to remove the thousands separator, you'll need to check which system is the baseline for calculating the percentages.  Also you may need to play around with `merge`'s `all` parameters to reflect the screenshow where you keep record 91 but not 45.

Comment: @GavinKelly Thx! Please have a look at my update! When merging the two datasets I all data rows that do not match are removed. Is there an option to keep them and to set the part where these rows do not match `null` or `empty string`?

Comment: Add an `all=TRUE` clause to the merge command.  It's not clear what the '10-20%' range should be in such cases.